# Call a custom function based on selected select field option

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, html-select, onchange

I got a problem with this code below.

I want to choose between 2 options. When i choose `"1"`, then `F1()` is called. When choose `"2"`, then `F2()` is called.

Unfortunately something is wrong with my code.

```js
function abc(element){
    var value1 = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
    
    switch(value1){
        case 1:
            F1();
            break;
        case 2:
            F2();
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<select id = "nextGeneration" onchange="abc(this)" >
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code is not working because `element.options[element.selectedIndex].value` returns string values and you are comparing them against integers. In the code below selecting 2 works because it has case for "2" but selecting 1 doesn't work

```js
function F1(){
console.log(1);
}
function F2(){
console.log(2);
}
function abc(element){
                var value1 = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
                switch(value1){
                    case 1:
                        F1();
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        F2();
                        break;

                }
            }
```

```html
<select id = "nextGeneration" onchange="abc(this)" >
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option> 

  </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="nextGeneration" onchange="abc(this)">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option> 

</select>

<script>
    function F2() {
        console.log("change 2");
    }

    function F1() {
        console.log("change 1");
    }

    function abc(element) {
        var value1 = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;

        console.log(value1);

        switch (value1) {
            case "1":
                F1();
                break;
            case "2":
                F2();
                break;

        }
    }
</script>
```

You need to set your cases in quotes, Ex: case "2".